# fetch previous record in sql by servlet

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp, servlets

Iam trying to fetch previous record in oracle by clicking submit button on browser, but exception is coming  **java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00905: missing keyword**, what I am doing wrong in this below code??

I have a table named as **abc** and its two columns named as **F** and **S** having 5 records.

Actually what I want to do is after clicking next button I am getting next record fetched from database but when I am clicking previous button, previous record should get fetched, it does not work. Where I am wrong??

For NEXT button I am sending to another servlet (NewServlet1.java) and just in place of PREVIOUS I wrote NEXT and it is working fine but for PREVIOUS button I replaced NEXT by PREVIOUS in sql query and put it in New Servlet but not working...

### home.jsp

```
<form action="NewServlet1" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="NEXT">
</form>
```

### **NewServlet.java**

```
String count = request.getParameter("count");
int c = 0;
if(count != null && count.matches("\\d+")){
c = Integer.parseInt(count);
          rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY 'F','S' OFFSET "+String.valueOf(c) +" ROWS FETCH PREVIOUS 1 ROWS ONLY");
    }
    else{

  rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY 'F','S' FETCH PREVIOUS 1 ROWS ONLY");
}

request.setAttribute("count",++c);
request.getRequestDispatcher("display.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

### display.jsp

```
<form action="NewServlet" method="post">
<input type="text" name="count"  value="<%(Integer)request.getAttribute("count")%>" style="display:none;">
<input type="submit" value="PREVIOUS">
  </form>
```

Comment: ya i tried but error coming java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: i removed PREVIOUS from query

Comment: @AlexPoole hii i am n't getting i removed d word PREVIOUS from the above query bt still getting that exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55639) and [syntax diagram](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABBADDD), the `FETCH` has to be followed by `FIRST` or `NEXT` (which are interchangeable). There is no `PREVIOUS` option. You aren't providing one of the expected keywords, so you get ORA-00905.

To go back a row you'd need to offset by one fewer rows than you think, based on your counter, then get `NEXT ROW`. So if you're currently looking at the 10th row, you'd need to offset by 8 and get the next one, which will be the 9th.

Comment: I modified like this bt not working-  OFFSET "+String.valueOf(c--) +" ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? You get an error, or the wrong data? Depending on what `c` is you might want `(c - 2)` to avoid seeing the original row again. Is `count` the row number currently being displayed?

Comment: sorry wrong data it is taking me to the first row and after clicking nothing happens